# Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple::render() in mailer causing WSOD

Tags: phalcon

I have a simple controller action that creates a `Guest` record and renders a template.

```
// First bind the form to our Guest:
$form->bind( $_POST, $guest );

// Validate and save, or show error messages
if( $form->isValid($_POST, $guest) ) {
    if( $guest->save($_POST) ) {
        $this->view->setMainView( 'confirm' );
    }
}
```

This works fine before I add any mailer stuff. However, when I add an event handler inside the `Guest` model which happens to render a template, the controller renders a WHITE SCREEN OF DEATH instead of my confirm template.

In `Guest` model:

```
public function afterCreate() {
    return GuestMailer::sendEmailConfirmation( $this );
}
```

In `GuestMailer` class:

```
public static function sendEmailConfirmation( $guest ) {
    // create/configure $email message

    $view = $guest->getDI()->get('simpleView');
    $view->render(                 // Works without this call...
        'confirmation_email',
        array( 'guest' => $guest )
    );
    $content = $view->getContent();
    $email->content( $content );

    return $email->send();
}
```

Note that when I remove the above call to `render()`, the confirm template is rendered successfully.

I thought components in Phalcon were supposed to be highly decoupled? Why is rendering a completely different template causing my controller's view to get messed up? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is caused by a peculiar configuration of the templating service, in a normal workflow it doesn't causes issues, they appears when you need to render "manually" a template as in your case, you can refer to this PhalconPHP forum discussion linked, in particular the answer refered by the link anchor:
http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/109/manually-render-separate-file-template-#C12015